# CUDA: calling library function in kernel

Tags: cuda

I know that there is the restriction to call only `__device__` functions in the kernel. This prevents me from calling standard functions like `strcmp()` and so on in the kernel.
At this point I am not able to understand/find the reasons for this. Could not the compiler just follow each includes in strings.h and so on while inlining the calls to `strcmp()` in the kernel? I guess the reason I am looking for is easy and I am missing something here.
Is it the only way to reimplement all the functions and datatypes I need in kernel computation? Is there a codebase with such reimplementations?

Comment: If you feel that you need to use C library functions in a CUDA kernel then you *may* have missed the point of GPGPU programming.

Comment: `strcmp()` is a simple function. Surely you could write an equivalent for your purpose.

Comment: example code for `strcmp()` is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcmp

Comment: @PaulR Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user124384: I think aland's answer below pretty much covers it.

Comment: @PaulR In that case, it's still not clear to me, even after reading that answer, why, if you want to, say, run `strcmp()` a trillion times, it's not a good idea to parallelize it on a GPU.

Comment: @user124384: firstly just let me say that my comment and aland's answer are from 2011, so things may have changed somewhat in the last 6 years. However CUDA and GPGPU in general tends to be all about SIMT, i.e. lots of parallel threads all running the same instructions. If you want to efficiently compare billions of strings in parallel with such an architecture then you would probably want to write custom code for this which keeps all threads in a warp busy, rather than using library functions such as strcmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the only way to use stdlib's functions from kernel is to reimplement them. But I strongly advice you to reconsider this idea, since it's *highly* unlikely you would need to run code that uses `strcmp()` on GPU. Please, add additional details about your problem, so a better solution could be proposed (I highly doubt that serial string comparison on GPU is what you really need).

It's barely possible to simply recompile all stdlib for GPU, since it depends a lot on some system calls (like memory allocation), which could not be used on GPU (well, in recent versions of CUDA toolkit you *can* allocate device memory from kernel, but it's not "cuda-way", is supported only by newest hardware and is *very* bad for performance).
Besides, CPU versions of most functions is far from being "good" for GPUs. So, in vast majority of cases compiling your ordinary CPU functions for GPU would lead to no good, so the compiler doesn't even try it.

Comment: This was a general question since i needed one or two standard functions in my latest CUDA projects. Currently I try to build a dictionary on the GPU so I will need at least a strcpy()

Comment: @Callahan There is thrust library with some pieces of STL ported to CUDA, but it has no string-processing capability, since it's very non-GPUish task. Using loops with number of iterations different in each thread is bad for performance. Hash-lookups (int32 or int64 comparison) are better, and than you could do `strcmp()` among strings with same hash on CPU. It also saves device memory.

Comment: This is indeed a good idea. As long as I do only want to lookup words... This would save Lots of memory! But how do I compute an unambigous hash which is smaller than 2^64 of a long (15 chars) word?

Comment: It's impossible to build absolutely unambiguous hash function, since even if we use 26-letter case-insensitive alphabet, 15-letter word bears ~71 bit of information, so you will have to handle collisions anyway (and I advice doing it on CPU). If you have words from natural language, just first 8 bytes of a word might make quite a good hash (and very fast one!). But finding really good hash-function that suits your needs is a task by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Standard functions like `strcmp()` have not been compiled for the CUDA architecture. I have not seen any standard C libraries for CUDA.