# How to run "host" functions on GPU with CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I'm going to run on GPU for example a `strcmp` function, but I get:

```
error: calling a host function("strcmp") from a __device__/__global__ function("myKernel") is not allowed
```

It's possible that `printf` won't work because gpu hasn't got stdout, but functions like strcmp are expected to work! So, I should insert in my code the implement of `strcmp` from the library with `__device__` prefix or what?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311288/cuda-calling-library-function-in-kernel

Comment: What makes you think "functions like strcmp are expected to work"? The CUDA standard library is explicitly described in the CUDA programming guide appendices. I don't see `strcmp`, or anything else from the C standard library `string.h`. Do you?

Comment: True, talonmies, but it would be nice to explain to him *how* he could add that function...

Comment: @talonmies.... look @ the below for a starting point for one possible parallel analogue.

Answer (score 2):

CUDA has a standard library, documented in the CUDA programming guide.  It includes printf() for devices that support it (Compute Capability 2.0 and higher), as well as assert().  It does not include a complete string or stdio library at this point, however.

Implementing your own standard library as Jason R. Mick suggests may be possible, but it is not necessarily advisable.  In some cases, it may be unsafe to naively port functions from the sequential standard library to CUDA -- not least because some of these implementations are not meant to be thread safe (rand() on Windows, for example).  Even if it is safe, it might not be efficient -- and it might not really be what you need.

In my opinion, you are better off avoiding standard library functions in CUDA that are not officially supported.  If you need the behavior of a standard library function in your parallel code, first consider whether you *really* need it:
* Are you really going to do thousands of strcmp operations in parallel?
* If not, do you have strings to compare that are many thousands of characters long?  If so, consider a parallel string comparison algorithm instead.

If you determine that you really do need the behavior of the standard library function in your parallel CUDA code, then consider how you might implement it (safely and efficiently) in parallel.

Comment: Look @ my updated answer...  I was simply pointing him towards a stepping stone.  Obviously you have to beware of types.  In this case it appears that the grabbed function would be safe, due to the types.

However, it is unoptimal in that it does not leverage the inherent parallelism.

And in the worst case (as with many other functions), it may not even be threadsafe, as you point out.

Anyhow, the next step clearly is the parallelize the function.  In this case this shouldn't be hard -- I outline a semi-optimized suggestion above.

Comment: Your implementation (3) was thread safe.  But some functions, such as `rand()`, which rely on static data, are not.  My answer is higher level: the OP assumes that standard library functions are "expected to work".  I wanted to explain why they might not, and why they should be ported carefully.  It's fine to suggest an optimized parallel implementation of strcmp, but it begs the question that I asked in my answer: "Do you really need a parallel strcmp"?  Your second code only works if all threads cooperate on the same comparison (which is likely to be overkill for short strings).

Comment: True, the original code is threadsafe as fortune would have it as it doesn't modify anything in its inputs.

Parallelism may be overkill in the case of very short threads, which would suggest a hybrid approach -- `if (size<LIMIT) OriginalStrCmp(src, dest); else ParallelVersion(src, srcLen, dest, destLen);` ... that would seem the best approach performance wise, with proper benchmarking to pick the right `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help atleast one person:

Since strcmp function is not available in CUDA, so we have to implement on our own:

```
__device__ int my_strcmp (const char * s1, const char * s2) {
    for(; *s1 == *s2; ++s1, ++s2)
        if(*s1 == 0)
            return 0;
    return *(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2 ? -1 : 1;
}
```