# Does CUDA kernel not support strncpy

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am getting following error:

```
error: calling a host function("strcpy") from a __device__/__global__ function("doDecompression") is not allowed
error: calling a host function("strlen") from a __device__/__global__ function("doDecompression") is not allowed
error: calling a host function("strlen") from a __device__/__global__ function("doDecompression") is not allowed
```

Is this true or is my compiler acting funny??

Comment: Yes, this is true. See quiestions http://stackoverflow.com/q/9648937/929437 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7311288/929437

Comment: The CUDA standard library is documented in the Appendices of the CUDA programming guide. What you see there is *exactly* what is supported. What don't find there is not supported. All of the functions defined in <string.h>/<cstring> fall into the latter category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Functions from the standard C library (like strcpy) are not supported from kernel code.

These functions were designed and written to work on a CPU and it would be very difficult to make them work on the device for a massive number of threads.

Comment: then how would you compare two strings on GPU. Can we use the strcmp function in the C lib and put __device__ in front of it?

Comment: Programmer: No, that will not work. You will either need a GPU string library or just write your own kernel to do the comparison.

Comment: Can you please help me write one?? I have been trying since the last 4 hours but it just does not work

Comment: @Programmer: there must be literally hundreds of implementations of strcmp floating around on the interweb - including the BSD, GNU, and Microsoft libc versions. Surely you find something to help with the search engine of your choice?